# Opening an Excel-File in a new instance and run Auto_open

Tags: excel, runtime-error, multiple-instances, vba

I have created an Excel workbook that uses Userforms as a Menu for users, meaning that they don't interact with the workbook itself. Usually, this is opened by double click with works perfectly.

Now, I would like to open this file from another excel file and to prevent users from being locked into the target workbook (since the userform is modal), I am opening it in a new instance.

I have looked into various methods (among them https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/570562-vba-open-another-instant-excel-run-macro.html), where I found code that seems to be working and also starts the Auto_Open-code (previous attempts opened the file but did not start the code) BUT since the target file has application-closing-code integrated (due to also being opened via double click), it gives me a runtime error (440) upon closing the target workbook since I believe that the Application.Quit-command is interrupting the Run-command and causing the error.

I also found someone with a similar problem (between access and excel but I believe its basically the same thing for this case) at https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=153101 but the suggestion of putting the closing code into the calling file does not work for me, since the target file gets opened independent from the calling file half the time.

Is there any way around this or maybe another method to open the target workbook from another excel workbook and also run the code after opening?
Also, if that is an option, maybe there is a way to always open the target file (no matter the source) in a new instance that does not involve administrator rights at all (because I don't have any)?

The relevant code pieces are as follows:

Source file (opening the target file):

```
Dim aExcel As Application
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim sReturn As String
Dim sArg As String
Dim sFile As String

' File to be opened
sFile = "C:\file.xlsm"

' Neue Instance
Set aExcel = New Application

With aExcel
    .Visible = True

    ' WB-Reference for opening of WB
    Set wbTarget = aExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFile)

    sArg = "'" & wbTarget.Name & "'!ModPublic.Auto_Open"

    ' Run Code within Targetfile (bc code does not start otherwise)
    aExcel.Run sArg

    ' Not reached due to runtime error:
    'aExcel.Quit
End With
```

Target File (gets open via auto_open and does its thing - afterwards gets closed via [x] on the userform):

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
' [x] is clicked (CloseMode = 0)
If CloseMode <> 1 Then
    ' deactivate Cancel
    Cancel = 1
    ' 1 wb is open, save file and quit application
    If Application.Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.Quit
    ' more than 1 is open, save file and close wb
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit of a workaround, but can you create a global variable in the target workbook, which specifies that the workbook is actually opened from the source workbook? And then use the global variable in the QueryClose sub with an if statement around Application.Quit?

Comment: I tried that but I don't know how to get back to the source wb. If I don't leave the application.quit or workbook.close, nothing happens.

Comment: Okay, I solved it in the ugliest way possible with On Error Goto in the source file that quits the target file in case of error. Thank you anyway. If anybody finds a better solution, I'd be happy to try - I usually avoid on error goto if I can.